# Replicate T-SQL ISNULL function logic into SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Databricks in order to join some tables that are stored as parquet files in ADLS. I'm importing the files, saving the dataframes as TEMP VIEWs and then build up the syntax for JOIN inside spark.sql('').

In the Join I have to replicate some SQL code previously developed by my colleagues that used T-SQL ISNULL function in this way:
`ISNULL(titledict.Category_Level_1, urldict.Category_Level_1)`
Basically they given the replacement value, thing which I cannot do with the ISNULL function from SparkSQL.
"titledict" and "urldict" are the aliases of 2 of the tables from the entire SQL JOIN logic.
Which would be the optimal way to replicate the ISNULL function from T-SQL in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) function which does the same. It returns the second value if the first one is null.

```
df.withColumn('test', coalesce(col('test_value'), lit('Fallback value')))
```

Comment: or the third, or the fourth, or the next ... add as many as you need

Answer (score 1):

Ifnull(expr1,expr2)
**returns expr2 if expr1 is null ,or expr1 otherwise**.
For eg
To replace null values with zero in databricks sql

```
Select ifnull(Null, 0) --returns 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).